# regex : match two different parts of same string

Tags: php, regex

I've got the following string:

> {!ex=track_created_f}track_created_f:[NOW/DAY-3MONTHS/DAY TO NOW/DAY]

I would like to match/extract **track_created_f** and **NOW/DAY-3MONTHS/DAY TO NOW/DAY**. The {!ex=track_created_f} might or might not be present at all times, so the regex should not rely on this part.

**However, it is the second track_created_f (and not the track_created_f which is a part of !ex=track_created_f) which I need to match.**

What I've got so far is the following ([see this link for live preview](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1g2)):

```
[^.*(\w+)\:\[(.*)?\]$]
```

However, this just gives me :

```
Array
(
    [0] => {!ex=track_created_f}track_created_f:[NOW/DAY-3MONTHS/DAY TO NOW/DAY]
    [2] => f
    [2] => NOW/DAY-3MONTHS/DAY TO NOW/DAY
)
```

What I'm having trouble to get a real grip on is how I can use regex to match only the part(s) of the string which I'd like to match, and only return that part. As it is now, (0) the entire string is being returned along with (1) the not so good match of **track_created_f** and (2) the match of **NOW/DAY-3MONTHS/DAY TO NOW/DAY**.

I've been trying to figure this one out by reading the docs, but I'm uncertain as to whether I'm getting things right - particularly the optional '?' clauses I've put in. Is that the right way to match subsets of strings at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^.*(\w+)\:\[(.*)?\]$]` is a wrong regex.  You are actually putting whole regex inside a regex character class.

The following regex is enough

```
/(\w+):\[([^\]]+)/
```

Comment: Thanks! This one seems to work very well, also when removing {!ex=track_created_f}.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct. It was the first answer which solved things at first try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:{\!ex=\w+}|)(.*):\[(.*)?\]$
```

That will make the `{!ex=track_created_f}` part optional.

See: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1gc

Comment: Thanks! This one works well, but not so well if I remove the {!ex=track_created_f} from the string. http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/1gb

Comment: @sbrattla If it's not there, then there's nothing to match against. Or by **track_created_f**, are you referring to the *second instance* of it in the haystack?

Comment: i'm referring to the first {!ex=track_created_f}. That part will be missing now and then, but I still need to match the second track_created_f. In other words, the regex should not trust that {!ex=track_created_f} will be present, but I still need to match the second track_created_f.

Comment: @sbrattla What I mean is, when you say you want to match **track_created_f**, do you mean the one in "{!ex=*track_created_f*}" or the one in "}*track_created_f*:[NOW/DAY"? It wasn't obvious based on the question and I assumed it was the first because second match is also part of a name/value pairing.

Comment: @sbrattla Since it's the second one you want to capture, simply put the parentheses around the second group.